# Bad interpreter error when setting up Tomcat for remote debugging

Tags: macos, tomcat, debugger

I'm trying to set up Tomcat for remote debugging, [following these instructions](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/BOOT/Setting+Up+Tomcat+For+Remote+Debugging).

After having done the complete process, I get this error when I try to run my `startup.sh` script:

```
-bash: ./startup.sh: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Operation not permitted
```

Let's notice that before doing that, I could start my Tomcat server correctly.
Does someone have an idea about where I could have made a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually seems like the problem comes from Mac OS. When I unlocked the startup.sh file in order to write the export command, it seems like the OS put the file in quarantine. The command xattr -d com.apple.quarantine test.sh solve the issue.

And each time I modify the concerned file, the problem arises. So I have to use the command every time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried launching using the Catalina instead of `startup.sh`? Have ran into similar problems before. Looks like in the guide you need to use Catalina to fire up the server.

Comment: Thanks bill, it actually seems like the problem comes from Mac OS. When I unlocked the startup.sh file in order to write the export command, it seems like the OS put the file in quarantine. The command xattr -d com.apple.quarantine test.sh saved me.

Comment: No bother good to hear its working

Comment: ok but I can't because I don't have enough reputations to do so after 2 hours ;)